# Safari opens new tab with rapidly changing URL

Tags: mac, safari, internet, web-browser, virus

**Potential virus**

Hi I recently went to a streaming website and after watching a movie I went on and did other things like surf the web

But two hours later in a next safari tab I noticed that It had rapidly changing URLs and it was basically a blank page but with different urls changing under seconds

I was wondering if my machine is compromised?